# Conditional UNPIVOT in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, unpivot

Let's say I have a table with an ID column, and several property columns
MyTable (ID, PI, P2, P3, P4)

```
ID  P1   P2   P3   P4
1   A1   B    C1   D1
2   C1   C2   B    NULL
3   C2   Z    NULL NULL
4   X    A1   C1   NULL
```

So, I need to write a query to find out how many distinct property values out there, no matter in which column they are.

```
Value Count
A1      2
B       2
C1      3
C2      2
X1      1 
...
```

I think I can get this by using UNPIVOT (correct me, if I am wrong)

Now, how can I get similar count but grouped by a number of non-null values in the row (the count of non-null values per row may, or may not include key columns, doesn't matter), i.e. output like this:

```
Value NonNullCount Count
A1      3            1
A1      4            1
B       3            1
B       4            1
C1      2            3
C1      4            1
C2      3            1
C2      2            1
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method, using `cross apply` for the unpivot:

```
select vals.p, t.NonNullCount, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             ((case when p1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when p2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when p3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
              (case when p4 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
             ) as NonNullCount
      from table t
     ) t cross apply
     (values (p1), (p2), (p3), (p4)) vals(p)
where vals.p is not null
group by vals.p, t.NonNullCount;
```